# CosmosDB Dotnet - Get All Items in a container

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to work out the simplest way to get all items in a container. I have seen a couple of ways of doing it that all seem more complex than it should be. Any ideas?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync()
{
    return _container.//Something
}
```

I'm hoping something as simple as this GetAsync method exists.

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync(Guid id)
{
    return await _container.ReadItemAsync<T>(id.ToString(), new PartitionKey(id.ToString()));
}
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`GetItemQueryIterator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.getitemqueryiterator?view=azure-dotnet) in an `IAsyncEnumerable`

> This method creates a query for items under a container in an Azure
> Cosmos database using a SQL statement with parameterized values. It
> returns a FeedIterator. For more information on preparing SQL
> statements with parameterized values,

*Example*

```
//Some Query
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetAllAsync<T>(string query) 
{ 
   var definition = new QueryDefinition(query);
   var iterator = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(definition);

   while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
      foreach (var item in await iterator.ReadNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
         yield return item;
}
```

Or you can supply null or an empty parameter list to `GetItemQueryIterator`

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetAllAsync<T>() 
{ 
   var iterator = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>();

   while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
      foreach (var item in await iterator.ReadNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
         yield return item;
}
```

**Usages**

```
await foreach (var item in GetAllAsync<Bob>())
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

If you install the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) nuget you can call `ToListAsync`

```
var results = await GetAllAsync<Bob>().ToListAsync();
```

If you don't want to take a dependency, you can roll your own

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static ValueTask<List<TSource>> ToListAsync<TSource>(
      this IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, 
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
   {
      if (source is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

      return Local(source, cancellationToken);

      static async ValueTask<List<TSource>> Local(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      {
         var list = new List<TSource>();
         await foreach (var item in source.WithCancellation(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
            list.Add(item);
         return list;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice, prefect solution! Thanks for that. I just dropped out the query string here and it worked prefectly ->  var iterator = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>();

Comment: @Sean interesting, I didn't know you could omit the query string altogether. Anyway glad it helped , good luck